# Transferring DB data between PHP and Javascript 2D array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays

I am attempting to get all the data from a MySQL db with PHP, initialise a 2D java array and populate it with the PHP data.

I am having trouble embedding JS in the PHP. I have marked up what is working and what isn't.

As you will see, some of the embedded java works but not all.

Any thoughts?

```
<body>

<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("XXXXXX.COM","guest","password");
    mysql_select_db("HHG", $con);

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else 
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles", $con);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "DB connection OK <br/>";
        echo "Found ";
        echo $numrows;
        echo " records <br/><br/>";
    } // EVERYTHING WORKS UP TO HERE
?> 


<script type="text/javascript">

document.write("THIS IS THE FISRT JS DOING SOMETHING"); // THIS DOES NOTHING
numrows = <?php echo $numrows; ?>; // THIS DOES NOTHING
string [][] hhgdata = new string[numrows][4]; // THIS DOES NOTHING
document.write("Records = " + numrows + "<br/>"); // THIS DOES NOTHING

</script>

<?
    $counter = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row["idimg"]; echo "<br/>";  //THIS WORKS
        $hhgtitle = $row["hhgtitle"]; //THIS WORKS
        echo $hhgtitle; echo "<br/>"; //THIS WORKS

        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript"> //THIS WORKS
            counter = <?php echo $counter; ?>; //THIS WORKS
            document.write("counter = " + counter + "<br/><br/>"); //THIS WORKS

            hhgtitle = <?php echo $hhgtitle; ?>; // THIS DOES NOTHING
            document.write("Title: "); // THIS DOES NOTHING
            hhgdata[counter][1]= hhgtitle; // THIS DOES NOTHING
            document.write(hhgdata[counter][1]); // THIS DOES NOTHING
        </script>

        <?
        $counter++; // THIS WORKS
    }
?>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you show the actual, final HTML instead of the source code? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm not generating HTML - I am simply moving MySQL data from PHP to Javascript. Just trying to get the last piece of the 2D array to accept data from PHP variables.

Comment: Whether you're generating HTML or JS - show the *end result,* not the PHP source code.

Comment: the extension of the array hhgdata from var hhgdata = []; to hhgdata[variable] = []; seems to stop things from running. If I use real integers in an example it forms and then displays the data. There are no errors displayed on my HTML page - just the document.write elements. Sorry. Noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up Java and JavaScript. For example this is Java syntax, you can't write this within a script tag which should only contain JavaScript:

```
string [][] hhgdata = new string[numrows][4];
```

The JavaScript arrays are dynamic, this should be enough:

```
var hhgdata = [];
```

When you want to add another array into it, as you seem to be doing later in your code, just do this:

```
hhgdata[counter] = [];
```

And then assign to the inner array:

```
hhgdata[counter][1] = hhgtitle;
```

You are also creating multiple assigning an unquoted string literal to variable with this (assuming `$hhgtitle` contains a string):

```
hhgtitle = <?php echo $hhgtitle; ?>;
```

It should be something like this:

```
hhgtitle = <?php echo '"' . $hhgtitle .'"'; ?>;
```

Finally, while it's not incorrect, your PHP `while` loop is creating multiple `script` elements in your HTML.

### **EDIT**

I have made the changes described above as well as in comments, copy-paste exactly and see how it goes:

```
<body>

<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("XXXXXX.COM","guest","password");
    mysql_select_db("HHG", $con);

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else 
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles", $con);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "DB connection OK <br/>";
        echo "Found ";
        echo $numrows;
        echo " records <br/><br/>";
    } // EVERYTHING WORKS UP TO HERE
?> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("THIS IS THE FISRT JS DOING SOMETHING"); // THIS DOES NOTHING
    numrows = <?php echo $numrows; ?>; // THIS DOES NOTHING
    var hhgdata = new Array(numrows); // THIS DOES NOTHING
    document.write("Records = " + numrows + "<br/>"); // THIS DOES NOTHING
</script>

<?php
    $counter = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row["idimg"]; echo "<br/>";  //THIS WORKS
        $hhgtitle = $row["hhgtitle"]; //THIS WORKS
        echo $hhgtitle; echo "<br/>"; //THIS WORKS
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> //THIS WORKS
    var counter = <?php echo $counter; ?>; //THIS WORKS
    document.write("counter = " + counter); //THIS WORKS
    hhgtitle = <?php echo '"' . $hhgtitle . '"'; ?>; // THIS DOES NOTHING
    document.write("Title: "); // THIS DOES NOTHING
    hhgdata[counter] = [];
    hhgdata[counter][1]= hhgtitle; // THIS DOES NOTHING
    document.write("<br />hhgdata[counter][1]: " + hhgdata[counter][1]); // THIS DOES NOTHING
</script>
<?php
        $counter++; // THIS WORKS
    }
?>

</body>
```

Comment: First script changed to:
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write("THIS IS THE FISRT JS DOING SOMETHING <br/>"); // THIS WORKS
 numrows = <?php echo $numrows; ?>; // THIS WORKS
 var hhgdata = [];
 document.write("Records = " + numrows + "<br/>"); // THIS WORKS
</script>

This seems to work.

Comment: The second script: 'while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $hhgtitle = $row["hhgtitle"]; //THIS WORKS
  $hhgtextlong = $row["text_long"];
  $hhgtextshort = $row["text_short"];
  $hhgidimg = $row["idimg"];
  
  ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  
   counter = <?php echo $counter; ?>; //THIS DOES NOTHING
   document.write("counter = " + counter + "<br/><br/>"); //THIS DOES NOTHING
   
   hhgdata[counter] = [];
   
   hhgtitle = <?php echo $hhgtitle; ?>;
   hhgdata[counter][1] = hhgtitle;  
   document.write(hhgdata[counter][1]); // THIS DOES NOTHING

Comment: Please edit your original questions and add these changes to the end of the post (preferably under an "Edit" subheading). It's difficult to make out what is and isn't working.

Comment: This is my first post so I can't add anything for a few hours. The second iteration of the array hhgdata[counter] = []; doesn't seem to work, then adding data as hhgdata[counter][1]=hhgtitle; and the subsequent document.write(hhgdata[counter][1]); doesn't do anything that I can see.

Comment: You are missing the correct PHP declaration in your second and third PHP script segments. They look like this: '<? $counter = 1;' and '<? $counter++;'. Add the word 'php' to them so they look like this:  '<?php $counter = 1;' and '<?php $counter++;'.

Comment: That makes no difference to the results - things seen to work fine with the <? script declaration all all elements work within it. The problem seems to the the array expansion of hhgdata[counter]=[]; that then stops the javascript.

Comment: All previous code using the variable declarations and transfer to a java variable work fine. the var hhgdata[counter] = [];
   hhgtitle = <?php echo $hhgtitle; ?>;
   hhgdata[counter][1] = hhgtitle;
   document.write(hhgdata[counter][1]); bit seems to be the issue here.

Comment: Doesn't work for me unless I explicitly add 'PHP' but it also doesn't give an error without. You need to see your page source. Pres alt+v+c if you are using IE or ctrl+u if you are using Chrome or FireFox. Check your output.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added the coded that works for me. Try to run exactly what I have pasted and try to get it to run.

Comment: This doesn't work if I put the $row["hhgtitle"] back in from my database. I get nothing at all.

Comment: I have updated the code, try it exactly as it is again. Also, did you see the page source as I suggested in my comment above?

Comment: That's it! The problem is in the mySQL datatypes for the non-functioning elements! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just take the PHP array of data and json_encode it? Then you can work with it in Javascript, see below:

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>;
```

You can learn more about how to do this here: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php